# Find the measure of the set: $B=\left\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in \mathbb R^n: \sum_{j\le n} (\sum_{i \le n} a_{i,j}x_i)^2 \le 1 \right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

> Let $A=(a_{i,j})_{i,j \le n}, \det A\neq 0$. Find the measure of   the set: $B=\left\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in \mathbb R^n: \sum_{j\le n} (\sum_{i \le  n} a_{i,j}x_i)^2 \le 1 \right\}$

I must find $\int_B 1 d\lambda_n=\int_B1dx_1...dx_n$ but I don't know how I can calculate integral of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Your set is $\{x \ | \ \|A x\|_2^2\le 1\}$, that is $\{x \ | \ A x \in U\}= A^{-1}(U)$, where $U$ is the unit ball. Therefore, the measure of the set equals $|\det(A^{-1})|\cdot m(U)$.

Note: the problem makes sense even if $\det A=0$. In that case the measure of the set equals $+\infty$.